# ravendb query where child list count = 0

Tags: ravendb

I have an object in ravendb called documents.   This is used to store the location and details of files.

this is the class view of the object:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Htmlform { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public IList<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
    public IList<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public IList<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public Users CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Users LastChangedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }
    public IList<DocumentElement> DocumentElements { get; set; }
    public MimeType MimeType { get; set; }
    public DocumentState State { get; set; }
}
```

In my UI, when a folder is selected, I want to get the files that have been assigned to that folder only, as the view shows teams as Folders, and inside that is folders for Users withing a team.

So I have built a query that is trying to get results where the folder is ( selected folder )  but the teams and users are unassigned.

```
var inFolder = await Session.Query<Document>()
                        .Where(
                            x =>
                                x.Folders.Any(a => a.Id == id) && x.Teams.Count() == 0 && x.Users.Count() == 0 &&
                                x.State.Name.StartsWith("Pub")).ToListAsync();
```

However this results in 0 records,   however I have this record available:

```
{
  "Name": "logo@1x.png",
  "Location": "https://removed.blob.core.windows.net/removed/fffa6220-69a4-48fa-9537-09006666a287.png",
  "Htmlform": null,
  "Client": {
    "Id": "Client-06ec8641-e206-41b4-b211-7c2bce2b9f33",
    "Name": "removed",
    "ClientEnabled": true
  },
  "Folders": [
    {
      "Id": "Folder-4e7eabc5-32e7-4d00-9800-4327aaac823f",
      "Name": "Testing",
      "DocumentType": {
        "Id": "DocumentType-f6e732d0-4fde-4956-981a-26e3d5397661",
        "Name": "General Documents",
        "Client": {
          "Id": "Client-06ec8641-e206-41b4-b211-7c2bce2b9f33",
          "Name": "removed",
          "ClientEnabled": true
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "Teams": [],  <-- empty as it should be
  "Users": [],  <-- empty as it should be
  "CreatedBy": { removed user object },
  "LastChangedBy": { removed user object },    
  "CreatedDate": "2014-10-29T00:00:00.0000000",
  "LastChanged": "2014-10-29T13:36:50.7311474",
  "DocumentElements": null,
  "MimeType": null,
  "State": {
    "Id": "DocumentState-b1b35556-acc3-4b07-b4fd-3bb7d6e764d1",
    "Name": "Published"
  }
}
```

I have also tried   `!x.Teams.Any()`

the created index

```
public Index_Auto_2fDocuments_2fByFolders_IdAndState_NameAndTeams_Count__AndUsers_Count__()
{
    this.ViewText = @"from doc in docs.Documents
    from docFoldersItem in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)doc.Folders).DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new { Teams_Count__ = doc.Teams[""Count()""], Users_Count__ = doc.Users[""Count()""],         Folders_Id = docFoldersItem.Id, State_Name = doc.State.Name }";
    this.ForEntityNames.Add("Documents");
    this.AddMapDefinition(docs => 
        from doc in docs
        where string.Equals(doc["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"], "Documents",    System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        from docFoldersItem in ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)doc.Folders).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new {
            Teams_Count__ = doc.Teams["Count()"],
            Users_Count__ = doc.Users["Count()"],
            Folders_Id = docFoldersItem.Id,
            State_Name = doc.State.Name,
            __document_id = doc.__document_id
        });
    this.AddField("Teams_Count__");
    this.AddField("Users_Count__");
    this.AddField("Folders_Id");
    this.AddField("State_Name");
    this.AddField("__document_id");
    this.AddQueryParameterForMap("Id");
    this.AddQueryParameterForMap("State.Name");
    this.AddQueryParameterForMap("__document_id");
    this.AddQueryParameterForReduce("Id");
    this.AddQueryParameterForReduce("State.Name");
    this.AddQueryParameterForReduce("__document_id");
}
```

So has anyone any ideas on how to conduct such a query, so thatI can get my result of one file pleaase.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I have worked it out.

```
var inFolder = await Session.Query<Document>()
                        .Where(
                            x =>
                                x.Folders.Any(a => a.Id == id) && x.Teams.Any() == false && x.Users.Any() == false &&
                                x.State.Name.StartsWith("Pub")).ToListAsync();
```

I have changed the query to any is false, on each of the items / objects    this also makes for a much neater index too